# Validation of "pure" Java libraries used in my Android app?

Tags: java, android

My use case is to build a portable Java library to be used not only on Android devices but also on non-Android applications.

As the standard Java features on Android are crippled ([not all APIs are implemented](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#supported-features) not just in terms of API but also in terms of language features, I was wondering if there is any way to validate a pure java project for compatibility with a specific Android configuration.

**Question:**

- Could a pure Java project (Maven/Gradle) be validated for Android (fixed API level) compatibility in a clean way?

Example of a "clean solution": Let's say that there is a Maven plugin that accepts Android SDK parameters (minSDK, targetSDK) and tries to compile the source code. If any errors are encountered it fails the build.

Comment: To the person who voted for the question to be closed: How can I rephrase to make the question less opinionated in your opinion?

Comment: Your question is too broad, not only are you asking three different questions, each of those questions themselves are probably too broad to answer well enough.

Comment: Agreed that I should stick to one question. I have now updated the post.